# Where to start python web page?

Tags: python, django, web

I'm at beginner level, I've given my 2 months at basics level in python. I'm familiar with algorithms, matrix and etc programming stuffs into python.

I want to give my whole life to `django`. But problem is i don't anything about web python stuffs except starting server on it.

I've started my server using:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000

def playServer():
    handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), handler)

    print("Serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

But when i call my simple web page, It still shows the codes of python, Please take a look at [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNJoA.png).

Please help me, How to make web page using python coding? Also let me know, Am i capable to start giving time with `django`? I've heard `django` is a framework, So i should give basics time to learn some python web page stuffs? right?

HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/, you have a lot to learn my friend but this tutorial will teach you how to get setup/install Django and give you a good base to start up with. Good luck with learning my man, any questions just comment below. BTW what you just did was not even Django at all, it was just starting a local webserver in python.

Comment: So, Should i jump directly to Django without learning any basics steps?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, teaching yourself is the hardest way to learn any skill. If you really do want to learn django, or anything else life, you're going to have to commit yourself, be patient, and ready to fail.

If you're really serious about this, I would work through [the Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html). This covers every aspect of django to get you started.

You're going to run into problems early and often. When you do so, stop and consort the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/), never be afraid to look directly at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django) and as always, come to SO with specific questions.

---

To answer you're more specific question, Django is nice in the fact that it hides all of the code you have above. For instance, once you have it configured, the line below will start a local server and you'll be able to interact with your web app through a web browser.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to execute the python script directly from browser.
First you must call the script from the command-line, then check the address on browser.

Also, you need to call the `playServer()` method at the end of the file to start the HTTP server.

then go the the address:port on your browser. It'll look something like this:
[image: result of running server]

**Now about the second question**,
I'll highly recommend you to start with Flask instead of Django.

It's simpler than django and best for beginners, and does less magic.
Also, as soon as you're comfortable with flask, you can easily move to django and have more fun while playing with it thereafter.